# How to use two different GoogleService-info.plist file in ios swift project for dev n prod?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, buildconfiguration

I need to use two different GoogleService-info.plist for working with dev and prod builds, currently I'm separating dev and prod by just changing "build configuration" in edit scheme, but now I need to have two different .plist files for dev and prod for working with google analytics, pushwoosh etc,

Comment: [Configure multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this case you need use different Targets with diff bundle id in project for **Dev** and **Prod**.
After that you will can link `GoogleService-info.plist` for this targets. And also I recommend create different folders in project directory 
Look at pictures. The first you create targets **Prod** and **Dev**

[image]

After create diff folders in project dict let's call them **GoogleProd** and **GoogleDev** and copy your `.plist` file to diff folders and drag to project. First file you need link with `TestProd target`

[image]

And the second file link with `TestDev target`

[image]

The final project directory will look like

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by diff target ?? actually i'm new to xcode , there are 3 xcode provided target in my project like project-test and-uitest , so are you suggesting any of them ??

Comment: but my project is almost done more than 70 % , so now do i have to duplicate my current target ??

Comment: Yes you can. New target will have the same links to files

Comment: you are awesome , sorry for late response , your way to organise builds is working fabulously for me.

Comment: This needs to be handled by using different schemes on the same target, not two different targets.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer, very clean helped me a lot !