# Best practice for CI/CD when building a SwiftUI for for different Firebase projects

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, testflight, cicd

I am new to iOS development (historically a full-stack guy) and I'm hoping some of you out there can share with me the best practice for setting up an Xcode project that will support a "dev", and a "prod" Firebase configuration.

I use Firebase as my backend and I have a project for each of the three environments.

Each environment has a `GoogleService-Info.plist` configuration file which I've renamed to `GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist` and `GoogleService-Info-Prod.plist`.

I use Xcode Cloud to build my app and deploy to TestFlight right now.

This is what I think should happen:

#### For DEV

1. Trigger build when a `feature-x` branch is merged into to `dev`
2. Set a value `Google-Config-File` in the `info.plist` to `GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist`
3. Use `FirebaseOptions` to initialize Firebase with the plist file defined in step 2
4. Deploy app to the internal TestFlight group

#### For PROD

1. Trigger build when a `dev` branch is merged into to `main`
2. Set a value `Google-Config-File` in the `info.plist` to `GoogleService-Info-Pro.plist`
3. Use `FirebaseOptions` to initialize Firebase with the plist file defined in step 2
4. Deploy app to the external TestFlight group

**NOTE** I did read this [suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362013/how-to-use-two-different-googleservice-info-plist-file-in-ios-swift-project-for) but I don't want to have two targets.  I would rather have one target and have the configuration set during the CI/CD (Xcode Cloud) process.

**NOTE** If you are curious how I configure Firebase at runtime based on a config property in the `info.plist` file here is how I do it ...

```swift
init() {
    // Lookup the value of the Google-Config-File from the info.plist
    guard let configFilename = Bundle.main.object(
        forInfoDictionaryKey: "Google-Config-File") as? String
    else { assert(false, "Couldn't find Google-Config-File in info.plist") }
    
    // Load the specified GoogleService-Info file.
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: configFilename, ofType: "plist")
    
    // Setup the Firebase options using the GoogleService-Info data
    guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
    else { assert(false, "Couldn't load \(String(describing: configFilename)).plist") }
    
    
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
}
```

Am I approaching this the right way?  Are there any steps I should change?

Comment: A rename approach won't currently work with Firebase Analytics. Details in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230

Comment: @PaulBeusterien that must have been an old issue.  As of today it is working perfectly for me.